# How do store bought bread keep so soft?

Tags: bread

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does commercial whole grain bread stay fresh for so long?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1897/how-does-commercial-whole-grain-bread-stay-fresh-for-so-long)

Does anyone know what store bread's secret is to making certain loaves of bread super soft for more than a day?  Is it generally some preservative that you normally would not add yourself?  Whenever I try to make a loaf of bread, it is best right out of the oven.  The next day, it does not taste as great unless I toast it. I am trying to find the world's most softest resilient bread to keep.  Thanks. :-)

Comment: Gah, did not see the duplicate post.